# What's Zepto.js alternative to jQuery's $(this).parent().parent().find('.active')?

Tags: javascript, zepto

What's **Zepto.js** alternative to **jQuery**'s `$(this).parent().parent().find('.active')`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see a `.parent()` method in the [API](https://github.com/madrobby/zepto), so you might just have to do this (untested!):

```
$($(this).get(0).parentNode.parentNode).find('.active').hide();
```

Answer (score 9):

This question is about 4 months old and the Zepto framework gets updated pretty regularly.

`$(this).parent().parent().find('.active')` now works.

According to the git repo source tree, this support was added in Dec 20, 2010 by Mislav Marohnić (commit hash 784de340).

Answer (score 3):

zepto has something like `Element#up`from prototype to search up the ancestry. It's called `closest`. You'll need to have a class or know who is the parent.

```
$(this).closest("div.parentclass").find('.active')
```

Comment: Thank you. I doubt if it's faster than karim79's solution, tho.

Answer (score 1):

Zepto has since implemented the .parent() method. See http://zeptojs.com/#parent